# Jaguar client for Flutter

Tags: flutter

1. Can someone tell me, when and why should I use [Jaguar](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jaguar#-readme-tab-) client
   for flutter rather than using using [HTTP](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) package.

   Just like we used to use Retrofit client for android instead of
   Volley(By Google) because it was fast. Is this the case with Jaguar
   too?
2. What are your thoughts on [jaguar_retrofit](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jaguar_retrofit) package?
3. Can someone also post a demo for how to use Jaguar package?

The reason why I searched for an alternative is because writing code for HTTP request doesn't seem to be a good code. It's just all static data without any annotations (unlike Retrofit).

Comment: Are you using Jaguar on the server?

Comment: Questions about opinions are off-topic on StackOverflow. SO is about concrete programming problems. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Hi, "Retrofit being faster than Volley" is a fact, if I'm not wrong.. so is Jaguar better than HTTP package? P.S Do you want me to edit my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Jaguar in Flutter development because this is the HTTP server framework.
Retrofit is good because of its convenience. You can declare network calls in one place and divide them if you have many APIs.